# Codeigniter pagination not showing first row of query result

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, limit, offset

As you can see below I am querying the database for a list of questions.

My model returns a count of questions ( `count_questions()` ) as well as the questions themselves ( `get_questions($args)` ) which are then paginated.

```
    $limit  = '10';
    $count  = $this->forum_model->count_questions();
    $offset    = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url']         = base_url() . 'forum/all/';
    $config['total_rows']       = $count;
    $config['per_page']         = $limit;
    $config['full_tag_open']    = '<div class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close']   = '</div>';
    $config['uri_segment']          = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['q']          = $this->forum_model->get_questions(NULL, $limit, $offset);

    $data['pag_links']  = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

The odd behavior I am seeing is that `count_questions()` returns '25' (which is correct).

But the pagination output shows 24 questions, skipping the first row/question in my database.

At first I thought this could be because of wrong offset, but it is set to 0 in the first page.

If I do NOT use pagination, my controller outputs all 25 questions to my view. So there seems to be something I'm doing with pagination limit/offset that may be the culprit.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Thanks for helping.

**Model (get_questions)**

```
function get_questions($forum_qa_id = NULL, $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL)
{
    ($forum_qa_id === NULL) ? ($forum_qa_id = "'%'") : ($forum_qa_id = $forum_qa_id);
    ($limit       === NULL) ? ($limit = 1) : ($limit = $limit);
    ($offset      === NULL) ? ($offset = 0) : ($offset = $offset);

    $query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT forum_qa.*,
           user_profiles.*,
           c.*,
           n.pid,
           v.*,
           Ifnull(n.ans_count, 0) AS ans_count
    FROM   forum_qa
           JOIN user_profiles
             ON user_id = forum_qa_author_id
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                      FROM   votes) AS v
             ON forum_qa_id = v.forum_qa_id_fk
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT forum_cm_id,
                             forum_cm_author_id,
                             forum_qa_id_fk,
                             forum_cm_text,
                             forum_cm_timestamp,
                             forum_cm_flag,
                             first_name  AS forum_cm_first_name,
                             last_name   AS forum_cm_last_name,
                             facebook_id AS forum_cm_fb_id,
                             picture     AS forum_cm_picture,
                             moderator   AS forum_cm_moderator
                      FROM   forum_cm
                             JOIN user_profiles
                               ON user_id = forum_cm_author_id) AS c
             ON forum_qa_id = c.forum_qa_id_fk
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT forum_qa_parent_id AS pid,
                             COUNT(*)           AS ans_count
                      FROM   forum_qa
                      WHERE  forum_qa_parent_id IS NOT NULL
                      GROUP  BY forum_qa_parent_id) AS n
             ON forum_qa_id = n.pid
    WHERE  forum_qa_id LIKE $forum_qa_id
           AND forum_qa_parent_id IS NULL
    ORDER  BY forum_qa_timestamp DESC
    LIMIT  $limit
    OFFSET $offset;     
    ");
```

**Model (count_questions)**

```
function count_questions()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT  *
    FROM    forum_qa
    WHERE   forum_qa_type = 1;
    ");

    return $query->num_rows;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using in your model?

Comment: updated the post - let me know what you think - thanks

Comment: And `forum_model->count_questions();`?

Comment: oops - just added it was well

Comment: If you delete the last 2 lines from the query in your `get_questions()` method, how many rows are returned?

Comment: @joseph I get all 25 rows - but when I use LIMIT OFFSET i get 24 rows

Comment: @torr let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2468/discussion-between-joseph-silber-and-torr)

Answer (score 1):

`return $query->num_rows;` should be `return $query->num_rows();`.

Also, try changing `LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset` to `LIMIT $offset,$limit`.

Comment: hey @rocket, thx for the suggestion - made the change but still no go - that row still doesn't show on the front end

Comment: @Torr: Try to change `LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset` to `LIMIT $offset,$limit`.

Comment: unfortunately no go, still omits that darn row - btw, it's the first row in my table that gets omitted - all others show fine - and as I say above in OP, if i don't use pagination, that first row shows up

Comment: @Torr: If you go to the 2nd page on the pagination, do you see your missing row?  Maybe you're `ORDER`ing them wrong?

Comment: the missing row is nowhere to be found, regardless of page

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->uri->segment(3, 0);
```

By default the function returns FALSE (boolean) if the segment does not exist. so i think isn't right!?

```
($offset      === NULL) ? ($offset = 0) : ($offset = $offset);
```

Comment: The 2nd parameter of `$this->uri->segment` is what to return if the uri segment does not exist.  `$this->uri->segment(3, 0);` would return `0` (not FALSE) if there was no 3rd uri segment.

Comment: You are using `$config['uri_segment'] = 3;` (The pagination function automatically determines which segment of your URI contains the page number. If you need something different you can specify it.) and `$offset    = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);` ... so what i think is you are on page 1 and the offset will also set to 1 (so first row will skipped"

Comment: and torr did you find the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is, when default page execute it start record from 1st row instead zero, that's why first row is missing. I applied following code to fix this problem

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

Please edit segment as per your request URL